# RecyclerView + SearchView Open Activity From Search

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am using `RecyclerView` to list some text and `SearchView` to search through the list and when the user clicks on a text in the list it opens a new activity specific that text. Before I used `SearchView` I just had my list of text and used switch statements if the user clicks on first line it opens first activity ect...

Now with the `SearchView` when you search for something at the bottom the result pops to the top of the list so the switch statement opens the first acitvity which is wrong.

So yea im stuck on how to open the correct activity for the correct text in the list when the user searches. Can someone help me with an example

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private static final String[] DUMMYTEXT = new String[]{

        "Text One ",
        "Text Two",
        "Text Three",
        "Text Four"
};

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private Adapter mAdapter;
private List<Model> mModels;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    mModels = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String dummyText : DUMMYTEXT) {
        mModels.add(new Model(dummyText));
    }

    mAdapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), mModels);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    final List<Model> filteredModelList = filter(mModels, query);
    mAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

private List<Model> filter(List<Model> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<Model> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Model model : models) {
        final String text = model.getText().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
}
```

ViewHolder.java

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private final TextView tvText;
private final Context context;

public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    context = itemView.getContext();

    tvText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = null;
         switch (getAdapterPosition()) {

             case 0:

                 intent =  new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
                 break;

             case 1:

                 intent =  new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                 break;

             case 2:

                 intent =  new Intent(context, ThirdActivity.class);
                 break;

             case 3:

                 intent =  new Intent(context, FourthActivity.class);



             default:

                 break;


         }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void bind(Model model) {
    tvText.setText(model.getText());
}
}
```

Model.java

```
public class Model {

private final String mText;

public Model(String text) {
    mText = text;
}

public String getText() {
    return mText;
}
}
```

Adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final List<Model> mModels;

public Adapter(Context context, List<Model> models) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mModels = new ArrayList<>(models);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_items, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Model model = mModels.get(position);
    holder.bind(model);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mModels.size();
}

public void animateTo(List<Model> models) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
}

private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<Model> newModels) {
    for (int i = mModels.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final Model model = mModels.get(i);
        if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<Model> newModels) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final Model model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!mModels.contains(model)) {
            addItem(i, model);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<Model> newModels) {
    for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final Model model = newModels.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = mModels.indexOf(model);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}

public Model removeItem(int position) {
    final Model model = mModels.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
}

public void addItem(int position, Model model) {
    mModels.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final Model model = mModels.remove(fromPosition);
    mModels.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}
}
```

Comment: You want text specific move from MainActivity to another activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here relates to data binding. Your `model` is not aware of what's expected of it in the event its chosen (clicked). The example below may seem convoluted, but its meant to highlight the issue.

Let's change your model class:

```
public class Model {

    private final String mText;
    private Class mLaunchClass;

    public Model(String text, Class launchClass) {
        mText = text;
        mLaunchClass = launchClass;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public Class getLaunchClass() {
        return mLaunchClass;
    }
}
```

Next, we edit your fragment code to incorporate this change:

```
private static final String[] DUMMYTEXT = new String[]{

    "Text One ",
    "Text Two",
    "Text Three",
    "Text Four"
};

private static final Class[] LAUNCH_CLASSES = new Class[] {
    FirstActivity.class,
    SecondActivity.class,
    ThirdActivity.class,
    FourthActvity.class
    ....
};
```

When creating the items for your adapter:

```
mModels = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < DUMMYTEXT.length; i++) {
    mModels.add(new Model(DUMMYTEXT[i], LAUNCH_CLASSES[i]));
}
```

Finally, your `ViewHolder's` reaction to a `click` event will change:

```
public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    context = itemView.getContext();

    tvText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
}

public void bind(final Model model) {
    tvText.setText(model.getText());

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = itemView.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, 
                                          model.getLaunchClass());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Your model can now supply the relevant information.

Comment: Great thanks alot Vikram works perfectly!! Just one question I will have a long list and each text will open the same layout file and I just replace the content in each class. Will it be beter to use fragments rather than acitvities and is it a good idea to open fragment from another fragment

Comment: @JacquesKrause If the same `layout` is being loaded, you can use a single activity that receives the relevant `text` through `Intent` using `Bundle`. This way, you'll only need to add a few lines of code when an update is required in future - as opposed to adding new activities. Moreover, if you realize that you missed some important feature, you will not have to edit `n` number of activities - only one activity will need to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct. because when the ListView reculcles with the changes to the adapter, it changes/refreshes the position of the new List Items as well.

But according to your logic position 1 will get to a specific Activity.

I think you will have to enforce the position into the Model, So rather than, getting the position using `getAdapterPosition()`

you can do something like,

```
mModels.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPosition();
```

Assuming that you have `getters and setters` for `int position` in your `Model class`